# Display data on Html page

Tags: html, javascript, css, python, django

I have a website that displays data from external files. But there is a problem with the display as in the attachment. How can I control the page size to display the full data without compression ??

[image: Example display data]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.